# error while calling jax-ws webservice hosted at weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws

I am using jax-ws webservice hosted at weblogic 10.3, while calling the webservice i am getting the below response

javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to receive message. caused by: java.io.IOException: null caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered

does anyone know why it comes?

Comment: i faced the same issue some time back,there could be reason that your response is not as it should be. have you tried TCPmon to see what is the response you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the response generated from webservice was not as it should be that is why i was getting this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I may be beaten down for resurrecting a solved problem but here goes.  Maybe this will save someone some time.

I introduced this error in a project that I was working on.   As it turns out, the IDE “helped” me by importing the old type of the same name in one of the row mappers.  my.proj.old.stuff.MyType instead of my.new.stuff.MyType.