# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered at welogic

Tags: java, xml, jpa, soap, weblogic

I deployed a webservice in Weblogic v10.3.5.0 and when i want to test from the Weblogic this error appears, the issue is that only appears when I get information from some tables, with others it works correctly. Someone could help me?

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to receive message.
at weblogic.wsee.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:94)
at weblogic.testclient.WebServiceOperation.invokeHttp(WebServiceOperation.java:515)
at weblogic.testclient.WebServiceOperation.addWeblogicHeadersAndInvoke(WebServiceOperation.java:386)
at weblogic.testclient.WebServiceOperation.invokeSimple(WebServiceOperation.java:322)
at weblogic.testclient.WebServiceOperation.invoke(WebServiceOperation.java:630)
at weblogic.testclient.WebService.invoke(WebService.java:463)
at Controller.callOperation(Controller.java:865)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:879)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:91)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)

    Caused by: java.io.IOException
at weblogic.xml.domimpl.Loader.load(Loader.java:101)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPPartImpl.createDocumentFromInputStream(SOAPPartImpl.java:145)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.createSOAPPart(SOAPMessageImpl.java:467)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.constructMessage(SOAPMessageImpl.java:225)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.<init>(SOAPMessageImpl.java:151)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:76)
at weblogic.wsee.connection.soap.SoapClientConnection.createSOAPMessage(SoapClientConnection.java:134)
at weblogic.wsee.connection.soap.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:515)
at weblogic.wsee.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:92)
... 42 more

    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.prime(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:80)
at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.setInput(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:99)
at weblogic.xml.stax.RecyclingFactory.createXMLStreamReader(RecyclingFactory.java:40)
at weblogic.xml.domimpl.Loader.createXMLStreamReader(Loader.java:66)
at weblogic.xml.domimpl.Loader.load(Loader.java:95)
... 50 more

     Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.prime(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:69)
... 54 more
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to receive message.
at weblogic.wsee.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:94)
at weblogic.testclient.WebServiceOperation.invokeHttp(WebServiceOperation.java:515)
at weblogic.testclient.WebServiceOperation.addWeblogicHeadersAndInvoke(WebServiceOperation.java:386)
at weblogic.testclient.WebServiceOperation.invokeSimple(WebServiceOperation.java:322)
at weblogic.testclient.WebServiceOperation.invoke(WebServiceOperation.java:630)
at weblogic.testclient.WebService.invoke(WebService.java:463)
at Controller.callOperation(Controller.java:865)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:879)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:91)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)

    Caused by: java.io.IOException
at weblogic.xml.domimpl.Loader.load(Loader.java:101)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPPartImpl.createDocumentFromInputStream(SOAPPartImpl.java:145)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.createSOAPPart(SOAPMessageImpl.java:467)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.constructMessage(SOAPMessageImpl.java:225)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.<init>(SOAPMessageImpl.java:151)
at weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:76)
at weblogic.wsee.connection.soap.SoapClientConnection.createSOAPMessage(SoapClientConnection.java:134)
at weblogic.wsee.connection.soap.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:515)
at weblogic.wsee.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:92)
... 42 more

    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.prime(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:80)
at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.setInput(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:99)
at weblogic.xml.stax.RecyclingFactory.createXMLStreamReader(RecyclingFactory.java:40)
at weblogic.xml.domimpl.Loader.createXMLStreamReader(Loader.java:66)
at weblogic.xml.domimpl.Loader.load(Loader.java:95)
```

PD: I speak spanish, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed the soap response you are receiving from WS matches the WSDL (and XSDs) you used to generate your client?

Here is another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618423/error-while-calling-jax-ws-webservice-hosted-at-weblogic) with a similar issue.